# Why are there more users in the data dump than on SO's users page?

Tags: support, data-dump, user-count

According to [Greg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/what-is-the-current-user-count-of-stackoverflow/4058#4058), there are 93,861 registered users in the data dump. However, on the [SO users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users), there are only 74,620 people (2132 pages * 35 users per page). How is this possible? Does the data dump contain deleted users? Is there a way to keep your account from getting listed on the SO/Users page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing SO user view doesn't count anonymous users (the Unknown (Google) ones) in its user list, but the data dump obviously has to include them.

Comment: Didn't even think about that possibility.

Comment: That's why they pay me the big bucks, TXI.

Comment: yes, the /users page is only registered (non-cookie-based, OpenID) users

Comment: Hadn't noticed Jeff's stamp of correctness until now.

Answer (score 2):

Abandoned accounts are removed from the database as detailed on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)

> We delete cookie-based unregistered accounts when:
>
> The user has not visited Stack Overflow in four months
> AND
> The user has less than 100 reputation
>
> We delete OpenID registered accounts when:
>
> The user has not visited Stack Overflow in four months
> AND
> The user has only 1 reputation

Comment: Are these users in the data dump?

Comment: I'm under the impression they are - but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

They probably cleared up a lot of duplicate accounts