# How many users does Stack Overflow actually have?

Tags: support, users

Stack Overflow has just surpassed [1000000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000001) <s>users</s> user ids. Yet if you go to the [`/users`](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) page, there are "only" 15655 pages. 36 users a page, that's "only" 563,580 users.

Since [unregistered users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999993/badp) also have their unique ids but don't show up in the `/users` pages, I'll assume there is difference there. But are about half of our members unregistered?

And there are users who are outright [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69). What gives? Does SO purge its users after some period of inactivity?

Comment: I think they only show users with either at least 50 or 100 rep.

Comment: @Adel Clearly that's not the case. If you go to the last page, you'll see users with 1 rep.

Comment: User ID 4637897 created around now.

Comment: See also a question on activity http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269334/how-many-active-users-contributors-does-stackoverflow-stackexchange-have/269335#269335

Comment: Are there also stats for the whole StackExchange/all sites of the SE network?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Select Count(*) From Users
```

Stack Overflow has **829,905** users at the moment (a few more by the time I submit this), then take away one for [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), here's a breakdown:

- Registered: **564,682**
- Unregistered: **265,189**
- Moderator: **32**

---

> And there are users who are outright deleted. What gives?

We deal with spam like everyone else...and users who ask to have their accounts deleted.

> Does SO purge its users after some period of inactivity?

Yes, an automated task cleans out accounts with literally no activity after a certain age.

Comment: Very few moderators

Comment: can this answer be updated please, currently `4,879,230` from the query explorer.

Comment: What is this query explorer? Can you please share the details.

Comment: @AniketThakur , I think that he talks about this http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: 08/10/2016: 5892453. This number grows very fast.

Comment: Isn't purging users dangerous? What if somebody wants their account back?

Answer (score 22):

First off, unregistered (cookie-based) accounts don't show up on the users page. So there's a big chunk of users who won't "count".

Then, [accounts *are* deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted) if they aren't active. (See link and [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) for definition of "active"). So those won't show up either.

Finally, there are accounts that are merged, and accounts that are simply deleted for other reasons (user asked for account to be deleted, spammer accounts, etc.)

#### See also

- [How many users are there on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/how-many-users-are-there-on-stack-overflow)
- [Is an anonymous user a user at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/is-an-anonymous-user-a-user-at-all)
- [Why are there more users in the data dump than on SO's users page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/why-are-there-more-users-in-the-data-dump-than-so-users-page)

Comment: Additionally, going to http://stackexchange.com/sites will show a count of registered and unregistered users per site.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to check how many users Stack Overflow has.

Here is a [sample query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215981/total-users-and-votes):

```
select count(u.Id) as "total users", sum(u.UpVotes) as "total upvotes", sum(u.DownVotes) as "total downvotes" FROM Users u
```

Results:

- Apr 18 '20: 12162499
- Aug 12 '19: ~10m (more accurately, 10843066)
- Nov 23 '15: ~4.9m
- Nov 11 '14: ~3.5m
- Oct 18 '11: ~800k (as per [Nick answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109612/191655))

Answer (score 10):

If you are interested in the exact and most up to date value you can get if from [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/):

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?&site=stackoverflow&filter=total

Or go to https://sostats.github.io and see the latest metrics:

[image: sostats - total number of users]