# Why does Query explorer not accept login credentials from other Stack Exchange sites and populate basic data?

Tags: support, login, data-explorer

Today I came across [Query explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). I had to log in again with a prompt to provide access when I already have accounts on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Also I had to fill all the profile details again.

So why is this behavior? When we log in to any other Stack Exchange site we use existing credentials, profile data is automatically replicated and we get 200 reputation points as a start. What is the reason?

Comment: Query Explorer - nice name, where did you see it??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109573/how-many-users-does-stack-overflow-actually-have/109612?noredirect=1#comment880343_109612